# Java, second maximum number without arrays or loops

Tags: java, max

I'm trying to create a Program that returns the second maximum number without using arrays or loops. It seems impossible, I thought about calculating the max number and then create a new method without the number that's the maximum but I don't know how to do it.

```
public class Program {

    public static double max10(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10) {

        double r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9;

        r1= max2(n1,n2);
        r2= max2(n3,n4);
        r3= max2(n5,n6);
        r4= max2(n7,n8);
        r5= max2(n9,n10);

        r6= max2(r1, r2);
        r7= max2(r3, r4);

        r8= max2(r6, r7);
        r9= max2( r8, r5 );

        return max2( r9, r5 );
    }


    public static double max2 (double n1, double n2) {

        return n1>=n2 ? n1 : n2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(max10(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)==10);
       System.out.println(max10(1,2,3,4,5,45,7,8,9,10)==45);
       System.out.println(max10(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,10)==10);
    }
}
```

Are there any tricks?

Comment: Curiosity, but why do u need such a thing ? sadistic interviewer ?

Comment: can you use `Collections` ?

Comment: You want to find the second largest number without using array. What is the means of input? reading from a file? Scanning the keyboard? Is the method signature with 10 parameters given to you? Please be clear..

Comment: No scanning or reading from a file, only the numbers that you put when you call the method.

Comment: I feel like having a max and secondMax variable here should do the trick?

Comment: Anyway OP has not accepted any solutions in the past, so I will save my 2 cents.

Comment: How could you do it with a max and secondMax?

Comment: If the greatest number comes twice, does it count as the second greatest too? My feeling is that the second max of [2, 5, 10, 10] should be 10, but you may also argue it’s 5?

Comment: @OleV.V. That is a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the max number using the method you were using above,
2. Instead of returning that max number, you then call a new method, max9, with all the numbers from the original minus the maximum value

   ```
   public static double getSecondMaxValue(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10){

       double maxValue = max10(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10)

       double secondMaxValue = 0.0;

       if(maxValue == n1)
           secondMaxValue = max9(double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10);
       else if (maxValue == n2)
           secondMaxValue = max9(double n1, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10);
       else if (maxValue == n3)
            secondMaxValue = max9(double n1, double n2, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10);
       ...
       ...
       else if (maxValue == n10)
            secondMaxValue = max9(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9);

       return secondMaxValue;

   }


   public static double max9(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9) {

       double r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9;

       r1= max2(n1,n2);
       r2= max2(n3,n4);
       r3= max2(n5,n6);
       r4= max2(n7,n8);
       r5= n9;

       r6= max2(r1, r2);
       r7= max2(r3, r4);

       r8= max2(r6, r7);
       r9= max2( r8, r5 );

       return max2( r9, r5 );
   }
   ```

Comment: This solved the problem, if anyone wants a look at it:

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a bit of a different approach. I don’t think it’s shorter, but I convince myself more easily it’s correct.

```
public class SecondMaxFinder {

    private double greatest;
    private double secondGreatest;

    public SecondMaxFinder(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4,double n5, 
            double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10) {
        if (n1 > n2) {
            greatest = n1;
            secondGreatest = n2;
        } else {
            greatest = n2;
            secondGreatest = n1;
        }
        fitCandidateIn(n3);
        fitCandidateIn(n4);
        fitCandidateIn(n5);
        fitCandidateIn(n6);
        fitCandidateIn(n7);
        fitCandidateIn(n8);
        fitCandidateIn(n9);
        fitCandidateIn(n10);
    }

    private void fitCandidateIn(double n) {
        if (n > greatest) {
            secondGreatest = greatest;
            greatest = n;
        } else if (n > secondGreatest) {
            secondGreatest = n;
        }
    }

    public double getSecondMax() {
        return secondGreatest;
    }

}
```

Call like this:

```
    double secondMax = new SecondMaxFinder(7.7, 2.1, 3.7, 8.6, 8.6, 9.2, 6.8, 9.6, 8.6, 8.6)
            .getSecondMax();
    System.out.println(secondMax);
```

This prints `9.2`.

Comment: I guess greatest = secondGreatest = n1; and fitCandidateIn(n2); instead of the first 7 lines should do the trick also

Comment: @dreamcrash I think not. Take args 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. You would set `secondGreatest` to 10 and the real second greatest will be missed.

Comment: If you want, it may work to set `greatest` and `secondGreatest` to `-Double.MAX_VALUE` and then `fitCandidateIn(n1)` etc. @dreamcrash

Comment: Yep, but the way you did it is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to reduce the 10 variables into pairs of max values.
10 values will get us 5 pairs of max values.

From the 5 pairs of max, we reduce it to 2 pairs of max + 1 value

That gives us only 3 values - The largest, 2nd largest, and a random value.

With 3 values, to get the 2nd largest, we sum all 3 values and deduct the largest and smallest from it:

```
public static double max10(double n1, double n2, double n3, double n4, double n5, double n6, double n7, double n8, double n9, double n10){

    double a = max( max(n1, n2), max(n3, n4));
    double b = max( max(n5, n6), max(n7, n8));
    double c = max(n9, n10);
    return (a + b + c) - max(max(a, b), c) - min(min(a, b), c); 
}

public static double min (double n1, double n2) {

    return n1<n2 ? n1 : n2;
}
```

Comment: Yep, very elegant solution

Comment: @dreamcrash Thanks ;)

Comment: Inside max 10 there's only 9 variables, but i want to compare 10 :S

Comment: @Green_Sam I thought you placed 9 arguments. Then it will be even easier! Let me adjust my code.

Comment: If i try your code with the following variables:                                                   System.out.println(max10(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)), i get that the second max is  6.

Comment: @user3437460 any ideas why?

Comment: @Green_Sam, that’s not so hard to see. With your example args, `a`, `b` and `c` become 10, 6, and 2 respectively. The second greatest of those is 6 alright. This in turn means that the logic in the answer is broken.

Comment: Also beware that subtraction of doubles that are far apart may lead to serious roundoff errors. Define `verySmall` as `-1e30`. Try `max10(verySmall, 5.0, verySmall, verySmall, verySmall, verySmall, verySmall, verySmall, 8.0, verySmall)`. It yields 0.0.

Comment: This code will only work if the second largest number is not in the same "grouping" as the maximum number. I.e. if max1 and max 2 are both in (n1, n2, n3, n4) or (n5, n6, n7, n8), then the logic will fail

Answer (score 0):

Program to find the Second max number without using an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class p17_second_max {
    public static void getSecondLargest(int total) {
        int b=0,c=0;
        int temp=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter The "+ i +"value: ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if (a>b){
                temp = a;
                a = b;
                b= temp;
                if(b>c){
                    temp = b;
                    b = c;
                    c = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Second max Value is: "+b);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter The total No. of input");
        int total = sc.nextInt();
        getSecondLargest(total);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Java Programs>java p17_second_max
Enter The total No. of input5
Enter The 1value: 15
Enter The 2value: 16
Enter The 3value: 3
Enter The 4value: 2
Enter The 5value: 35
Second max Value is: 16
```